# Deserializing Finagle Response

Tags: java, future, finagle

I'm writing Unit Test for a Finagle Controller and I'm having a hard time deserializing the Response from a twitter Future in order to validate. When I print the `Future`, I can see all the content, but when I do an `Await.result()`, I get a null pointer. I keep getting the same result:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.twitter.finagle.http.Response

This is my code:

```
        Future
            .value(response)
            .onSuccess(cons(r -> {
                try {
                    Response response1 = Await.result(r);
                    logger.info("response1: {}", response1);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }));
```

Any suggestions into how to deserialize the Future into an object I can check values against?

This is the whole stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.twitter.finagle.http.Response
at com.fitbit.sleep.score.http.SleepScoreControllerUnitTest.lambda$testGetByListIsSuccessful$0(SleepScoreControllerUnitTest.java:83)
at com.twitter.util.Function$$anon$4.apply(Function.scala:122)
at com.twitter.util.Function$$anon$4.apply(Function.scala:121)
at com.twitter.util.Future$$anonfun$onSuccess$1.apply(Future.scala:1820)
at com.twitter.util.Future$$anonfun$onSuccess$1.apply(Future.scala:1819)
at com.twitter.util.ConstFuture$$anon$8.run(Future.scala:2131)
at com.twitter.concurrent.LocalScheduler$Activation.run(Scheduler.scala:198)
at com.twitter.concurrent.LocalScheduler$Activation.submit(Scheduler.scala:157)
at com.twitter.concurrent.LocalScheduler.submit(Scheduler.scala:274)
at com.twitter.concurrent.Scheduler$.submit(Scheduler.scala:109)
at com.twitter.util.ConstFuture.respond(Future.scala:2127)
at com.twitter.util.Future.onSuccess(Future.scala:1819)
at com.fitbit.sleep.score.http.SleepScoreControllerUnitTest.testGetByListIsSuccessful(SleepScoreControllerUnitTest.java:81)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace? The error message you posted indicates you are performing some kind of cast in your code but I saw no cast in the code you posted.

Comment: @Abra, updated with the whole stack trace

Comment: `Response response1 = Await.result(r);` should be `String response1 = Await.result(r);`. This is because the type of `response1` should be same as type of `response`.

Comment: @RajkumarNatarajan, it won't let me do that. Since that method returns a Response type specifically